# Simple AngularJS Controller Demo Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller, angular-ngmodel

I have been using AngularJS for some time now and this particular code block is not difficult by any means, but it's not working and there must be something extremely **simple** that I am missing here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
  <head>
    <title>Simple ngRepeat with Data-Binding</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name
      <br />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
      <br />
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">
          {{ cust.name }} ({{ cust.city | uppercase }})
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
          {name: 'Bob', city: 'Atlanta'},
          {name: 'James', city: 'Orlando'},
          {name: 'Miles', city: 'Harlem'},
          {name: 'Carter', city: 'San Francisco'}
        ];
      }
    </script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As of now, this code produces a **blank page**. There should be an unordered list with **four records** and for example, typing 'Bob' in the input box should filter the records down to the only one that contains the name 'Bob'.

This demo was already working when the AngularJS code was inline and there was no controller. I had used **ngInit** in order to supply the customer array. When I attempted to place the customers in their own controller, I started receive a blank page.

I'm sure I just need a second pair of eyes to look over this very simple example.

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Could you post your javascript code? By the way, you should declare your `ng-app`

Comment: remove `data` from `data-ng-controller`. `ng-controller` is sufficient.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because it is not valid angular syntax for a controller (if that snippet of js is all of your angular code)

Comment: You are missing your angular bootstrapping functions

Comment: @Hardik Vaghani - data-ng-controller or ng-controller is the same, except that prefixing with data- will allow the HTML to pass validation.

Comment: Check if your script  "angular.min.js" is the path. Try running it in jsfiddle, it should work. I don't think there any wrong with the code. I believe the angularjs min is not in the path. try debugging the code in browser

Comment: @aksappy - he is bootstrapping his application with 'data-ng-app=""'

Comment: @Mindsect Team : please check your console log for error "'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: Your sample is correct. i think `<script src="angular.min.js"></script>` not loaded correctly. check it.

Comment: @daan.desmedt I receive the same "SimpleController' is not a function error when I use Angular 1.3.1. However, when I use 1.2.23, the declaration of an empty app name (for demo purposes only) has no affect on this skeleton demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Simple ngRepeat with Data-Binding</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name
      <br />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
      <br />
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">
          {{ cust.name }} ({{ cust.city | uppercase }})
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('app', []).controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
      function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
          {name: 'Bob', city: 'Atlanta'},
          {name: 'James', city: 'Orlando'},
          {name: 'Miles', city: 'Harlem'},
          {name: 'Carter', city: 'San Francisco'}
        ];
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Multiple things you could change in the demo.

1. You should create a new angular module

   `var module = angular.module(name, [dependencies])`
2. That module should be bootstrapped using ng-app

   `ng-app="nameOfApp"`
3. Controller should be added to the defined module

   `module.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);`

EDIT: Same outcome without specifying a module

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
  <head>
    <title>Simple ngRepeat with Data-Binding</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name
      <br />
      <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
      <br />
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">
          {{ cust.name }} ({{ cust.city | uppercase }})
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
          {name: 'Bob', city: 'Atlanta'},
          {name: 'James', city: 'Orlando'},
          {name: 'Miles', city: 'Harlem'},
          {name: 'Carter', city: 'San Francisco'}
        ];
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am conducting a class on the different facets of Angular, and this is just step 2, as step 3 will entail creating an actual module and encapsulating the entire code block inside of it. Is it impossible to run a controller without declaring a module or using data-ng-app="" as the app declaration?

Comment: @MindsectTeam Yeah, it is possible. In fact, I've takes your source code, added correct version of angular to <head> and it just runs as expected. (Updated my answer with that running version as well).

hmm.Not sure why it's showing a blank page for you.

Maybe the `angular.min.js` you're referring to does not exist?

Comment: Interesting! Our dev team is running everything in Angular 1.3.1. However, when I use the version of Angular you used in your second demo (1.2.23), everything works fine! Thank you for your fresh perspective. Informative and troubling at the same time. I will look more into this.